# Reposition dialog controls when resizing a dialog so that they are consistent between operating systems using mfc C++

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog, resize

Currently I'm repositioning dialog controls when the dialog is resized like this:

```
// Get the list control rect.
CRect listRect;
list->GetWindowRect(&listRect);
ScreenToClient(listRect);

// Get the dialog Rect.
CRect dialogRect;
GetWindowRect(&dialogRect);
ScreenToClient(dialogRect);

list->MoveWindow(listRect.left, listRect.top,
                 dialogRect.right - (2 * listRect.left), dialogRect.bottom - 100);
```

This works great in Windows XP, but when I tried in Windows Vista the positioning was off. I think this must be down to larger dialog borders and captions in Windows Vista dialogs, and the fact that `GetWindowRect` has the following entry in the documentation:

> The dimensions are given in screen coordinates relative to the upper-left corner of the display screen. The dimensions of the caption, border, and scroll bars, if present, are included.

So my question is, how do I reposition dialog controls when resizing a dialog so that they are consistent between operating systems? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [GetClientRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcy418as%28VS.80%29.aspx) instead of GetWindowRect followed by ScreenToClient -- the former returns the extents of the client part of the window (i.e. without borders), whereas the latter retrieves the extents of the whole window including non-client parts (albeit in client coordinates).

```
// Get the list control rect.
CRect listRect;
list->GetWindowRect(&listRect);
dlg->ScreenToClient(&listRect);

// Get the dialog Rect.
CRect dialogRect;
dlg->GetClientRect(&dialogRect);

list->MoveWindow(listRect.left, listRect.top, dialogRect.right - (2 * listRect.left), dialogRect.bottom - 100);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply avakar, but as GetClientRect returns the position in client coordinates it can't take into account the original position of the control as stated in the resource file. The code above positions the control so that it fills the whole upper half of its parent's dialog.

Comment: @Jon, you're right, you need to get the control rect in the dialog's coordinates. You do need to use GetClientRect to get the size of the dialog though. See the edited code.